Get files from USB storage device on android
I do not know how to access files on an USB device from android device.
I can get Device
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)act.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService); IDictionary<string, UsbDevice> devicesDictionary = manager.DeviceList; UsbDevice dvc = devicesDictionary.ElementAt(0).Value;
and take path to device file, from parameters. But whats next step? I need mount it somewhere to have acceess or what?

You can refer to this case: How to get result of granting permission to open and read from usb serial port in .NET Maui on Android platform?.
